# Prove: $L^p(X)$ is not contained in $L^q(X)$ iff $X$ contains sets of arbitrarily small positive measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $(X,M, μ)$ be a measure space and $0 < p < q ≤ ∞$. Prove: 
>   $L^p(X)$ is not contained in $L^q(X)$ iff $X$ contains sets of arbitrarily small positive measure.

My work:

I proved the forward direction. For backward direction, considering $q<\infty$, if I take disjoint sets $E_n\subset X$ such that $0<\mu(E_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$, then for $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)^{(-1/q)}\chi_{E_n}$, I can show that $f\in L^p$ and $f\notin L^q$.

Now for the case $q=\infty$ how can I find a function $g$ so that $g\in L^p$ and $g\notin L^\infty$. Can anybody please give me a hint?

**EDIT:** Does $g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{E_n}$ will work? I can prove that $g\in L^p$. But struggling to prove that $g\notin L^\infty$. Any ideas?

Comment: If your $E_n$ are disjoint, then $g$ will be bounded. You need $\sum c_n \chi_{E_n}$ with $c_n \to \infty$ such that $\sum c_n^p \mu(E_n) < \infty$. You know $\mu(E_n) < 2^{-n}$, so e.g. $c_n^p = 2^{n/2}$ will do.

Comment: @DanielFischer: But I think we cannot prove that this function is in $L^p$

Comment: It was constructed to be in $L^p$. That's what the finiteness of the sum says (with measurability considered obvious).

Comment: But $\sum 2^{n/2}\mu(E_n)<\sum{\sqrt{2}}$. We know that $\sum{\sqrt{2}}$ diverges. Does it follow that $\sum 2^{n/2}\mu(E_n)$ converges?

Comment: You have $$2^{n/2}\mu(E_n) < 2^{n/2} 2^{-n} = 2^{-n/2} = \biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\biggr)^n.$$

Comment: Oh thanks. I have done a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $L^p\not\subset L^q$, then there is some $f \in L^p \setminus L^q$. Put $A_t=\{x: \vert f(x) \vert \geq t\}$. Then

$$\vert \vert f \vert \vert_p^p = \int \vert f \vert^p \geq t^p\mu(A_n) .$$

That is,

$$\mu(A_n) \leq \vert \vert f \vert \vert_p^p \frac{1}{t^p} \to 0; \space \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$

However, if $\mu(A_n)=0$, for some $t$, then $\vert \vert f \vert \vert_\infty \leq t$ then

$$\vert \vert f \vert \vert_q^q=\int \vert f \vert^p \int \vert f \vert^{q-p} \leq \int \vert f \vert^p \vert \vert f \vert \vert_\infty^{q-p}<\infty$$

contradicting $f \not\in L^q$.

Suppose $X$ contains sets of arbitrary small positive measure. Choose a measurable set $A_1$ with $\mu(A_1) \in (0,1]$ and inductively choose $A_n$ measurable with $\mu(A_n) \in (0,\frac{1}{3}\mu(A_n)]$ so that $\mu(A_n) \in (0,\frac{1}{3^n}]$ and moreover,

$$\mu(A_{n+k}) \in (0,\frac{1}{3^k}\mu(A_n)].$$

Then put $E_n=A_n \setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_{n+k}$. Then the $E_n$ have positive measure and are disjoint, for any $a_n \geq 0$, one has $f=\sum_n a_n \chi_{E_n}$ and

$$\int \vert f \vert^p = \sum_n a_n^p \mu(E_n).$$

Choosing $a_n=\mu(E_n)^{-\frac{1}{q}}$ one has that $\int \vert f \vert^p \leq \sum_n \frac{1}{3^{n(1-\frac{q}{p})}}<\infty$ forcing $f \in L^p$ but $\int \vert f \vert^q$ becomes $\sum_n 1 = \infty$ thus $f \not\in L^q$.